# how to find the lower bound and lub?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

> Given the set $P=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and the partial order < on P defined by
>           $$(a,b)<(c,d)\text{ if and only if }\operatorname{max}(a,b)\text{ is less than }\operatorname{max}(c,d).$$
>
> Let $S=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}.$  Describe each of the following.
>
> (i)   The minimal elements of $S$.
>
> (ii)  The maximal elements of $S$.
>
> (iii) The lower bounds of $S$.
>
> (iv)  The upper bounds of $S$.
>
> (v)   The lub of $S$.
>
> (vi)  The glb of $S$.

I think that (i) $(0,0)$ is the minimal element of $S,$ (ii) the maximal element is infinity, (iii) the lower bounds of $S$ would be $(x<0,y<0),$ (iv) the upper bound of $S$ is infinity, and (vi) there is no glb of $S.$ I don't know what the lub of $S$ would be.

But I am told that $(0,0)$ is included in the lower bound? But then $(0,-1)$ would be a contradiction, since $\operatorname{max}(0,-1)$ not less than $\operatorname{max}(0,0)$?

Comment: This was asked exactly yesterday.

Comment: in yesterday,the condition is iff a<c&&b<d,in this question the condition is  (a,b)<(c,d) max(a,b)less than max(c,d)

Comment: This is still at the core the same question. You still haven't shown us your thoughts and it's still presented like a homework question.

Comment: sorry,i edited my idea on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to go would be to develop a visual understanding for how the partial order works.

Let's start with an arbitrary point of $P,$ say $(a,b).$ We can picture this as being somewhere on the $xy$-plane with integer coordinates. However, given the fact that $\max(a,b)$ comes into play in the definition of the partial order, it will probably make a difference whether our $x$-coordinate is equal to, greater than, or less than our $y$-coordinate. This suggests that we should start by addressing these three cases separately.

---

First, let's consider the case that our $x$- and $y$-coordinates are equal. That is, we're considering a point on the line $y=x$ with integer coordinates, say $(a,a).$ What would it mean to have $(a,a)<(c,d)$? Well, since $\max(a,a)=a,$ then by definition, we would have $a<\max(c,d),$ but again, that will vary, depending on the relationship between $c$ and $d.$ One possibility is that $\max(c,d)=c,$ so by definition, we have $a<c,$ meaning (visually) that $(c,d)$ is to the right of the line $x=a.$ The other possibility is that $\max(c,d)=d,$ so that $a<d,$ meaning (visually) that $(c,d)$ is above the line $y=a.$

Consequently, if we have a point on the line $y=x,$ then the greater points will be above it and/or to the right of it.

[image]

Here's a graph, with the point $(a,a)$ in red. The points above the line $y=a$ and the points to the right of the line $x=a$ will be greater than $(a,a).$ Put another way, the points outside of the region containing $(a,a)$ and enclosed by the dashed lines will be greater than $(a,a).$ The points in black on this graph will all be greater than $(a,a).$ No points incomparable to or less than $(a,a)$ are shown on this graph.

---

Second, let's consider the case that our $x$-coordinate is greater than our $y$-coordinate. That is, we're considering a point ***below*** the line $y=x$ with integer coordinates, say $(a,b).$ What would it mean to have $(a,b)<(c,d)$? Well, $\max(a,b)=a,$ so by definition, we would have $a<\max(c,d).$ If $\max(c,d)=c,$ then by definition, we have $a<c,$ meaning (visually) that $(c,d)$ is to the right of the line $x=a.$ The other possibility is that $\max(c,d)=d,$ so that $a<d,$ meaning (visually) that $(c,d)$ is above the line $y=a.$

Consequently, if we have a point $(a,b)$ with $a>b,$ then the greater points will be above and/or to the right of the point $(a,a).$ Put another way, if $(a,b)$ is below the line $y=x$, then we look to the point on $y=x$ that is directly above $(a,b)$--the points greater than $(a,b)$ will be above and/or to the right of that point.

[image]

---

Finally, let's consider the case that our $y$-coordinate is greater than our $x$-coordinate. That is, we're considering a point ***above*** the line $y=x$ with integer coordinates, say $(a,b).$ In much the same way as the second case, we find that the points greater than $(a,b)$ are those above the line $y=b$ or to the right of the line $x=b.$

Consequently, if we have a point $(a,b)$ with $a<b,$ then the greater points will be above and/or to the right of the point $(b,b).$ Put another way, if $(a,b)$ is below the line $y=x$, then we look to the point on $y=x$ that is directly to the right of $(a,b)$--the points greater than $(a,b)$ will be above and/or to the right of that point.

[image]

---

Note that in each case, we wound up finding a point on $y=x$ to make the comparison. This lets us split up the points of $P$ into "levels" of a sort.

[image: level sets of P]

Here, we see that our points have been divided up into somewhat L-shaped regions, with each region extending infinitely leftward and downward from the line $y=x.$

The points in any given region will be incomparable to each other--for example, none of the following points will be greater than any of the other following points: $$\dots,(-3,-1),(-2,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,-2),(-1,-3),\dots$$ On the other hand, points in more upward/rightward regions will be greater than points in more downward/leftward regions.

Consequently, we immediately see that any point of $P$ that is below the $x$-axis and to the left of the $y$-axis (that is, having both coordinates negative) will be less than every element of $S,$ so will be a lower bound of $S.$ However, since $(0,0)$ is not greater than the points on the negative $y$-axis or negative $x$-axis, then points on one of the two negative axes will ***not*** be lower bounds of $S$.

Now let's take a look at just points of $S.$

[image: level sets of S]

Immediately, we see that $(0,0)$ is the least element of $S,$ since it is in the most downward/leftward region. Consequently, it is the only minimal element of $S,$ and is the greatest lower bound--that is, $\operatorname{glb}(S)=(0,0).$ However, the regions extend infinitely upward/rightward from there, so $S$ has no maximal elements, no upper bounds, and no least upper bound. "Infinity" is not an ordered pair of integers, so we cannot say that it is a maximal element of $S,$ nor that it is an upper bound of $S$ in $P.$

---

To sum up the discussion above, we have the following

> **Claim**: Let $L$ be the set of lower bounds of $S$ in $P.$ Then $$L=\bigl\{(x,y)\in P:x<0\text{ and }y<0\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}.$$ In particular, $(0,0)$ is the greatest element of $L$, meaning that $\operatorname{glb}(S)=(0,0).$

See if you can prove this Claim. If you have any questions about what I've written, or want to bounce your ideas off of someone, please leave a comment below.

Comment: pardon,i am wondering whether the Given the set P=Z×Z and the partial order < on P defined by (a,b)<(c,d) iff a less than c and b less than d. prove the same graph beacause a<b and c<d but (0,0) is not included in S.

Comment: What I am  confused is that why 0,0 is included in 
Lower bound of S in this question 
But not in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160622/how-to-list-out-the-partial-order

Comment: Is there part of one of the answers that you don't understand? I will clarify, if I need to. The short explanation is that they aren't the same partial order, so they have different properties.

Comment: I added some pictures to the other answer. Hopefully, that will make things clearer.